# Custom Chatter Implementation

Tags: chatter, customer-community, community-builder

I have written a lightning component to show custom chatter functionality.The chatter comments which are given by the system admins are not visible to the community users where as the comments given by the community users are visible to the system admin. I have used below code to retrieve chatter comments.

```
ConnectApi.FeedElementPage comments  = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(Network.getNetworkId(), 
ConnectApi.FeedType.Record,recordId,25,
ConnectApi.FeedDensity.AllUpdates,null,100,
null,false);
```

Comment: looks like a profile/permissions issue

Comment: We have customer community plus user license and all permission are checked and it looks good. But comments are not populating.